# Chartjs Bar Chart add background color to value labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have bar charts with value on top using [chartjs-plugin-labels](https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels), and some values bumping to each other as image shown below on highlighted values

[image: bar charts]

How do I add `background color` to the values or is there any other nice solutions?

you can see my code here, please click Show Files and then choose `bar-chart.html`

https://replit.com/@panjigemilang/html?v=1

Answer (score 0):

you can user plugin option of chart js as per below code.

```
plugins: {
      
      datalabels: {
        color: "#000",
        backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
        font: {
          weight: "bold",
          size: 12
        },
        formatter: Math.round,
        anchor: "end",
        offset: -20,
        align: "start"
      },
    }
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-datalabels  => You can use this plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-labels  => This is very old plugin

Comment: okay I'll try it later. thankyou

Comment: hey I tried ur solution but it doesn't work. now the values is gone

Comment: Can you share your code so we can look into that

Comment: hey I just edited and put a link there. please kind to check out